# Error: Abort fetching component for route: "/home" when trying to use router.replace within a useEffect

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm currently working on a project using Next.js v13.3.0 where I'm storing state within my search params. I have a custom hook that I've created that allows me to:

1. Set my default state for my search params on load
2. Access the latest state within my search params
3. Update my search params

I'm doing this using next's `useRouter`. and `router.replace`

here is the structure of the custom hook.

```
export const useUrlSearchParams = (defaults) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { query } = router;

  const [urlSearchParams, setUrlSearchParams] = useState(null);

  // Set searchParams when router is ready
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      const { search } = query;
      const decodedSearchParams = search
        ? deserializeSearchParams(search)
        : (defaults);
      setUrlSearchParams(decodedSearchParams);
    }
  }, [router.isReady, query, defaults]);

  // Update URL when searchParams changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (urlSearchParams !== null) {
      const serializedSearchParams = serializeSearchParams(urlSearchParams);
      if (query['search'] !== serializedSearchParams) {
        query['search'] = serializedSearchParams;
        router.replace({ query }, undefined, { scroll: false });
      }
    }
  }, [urlSearchParams, query, router]);

  const updateUrlSearchParams = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      if (urlSearchParams) {
        // Need a deep clone made because merge below will update the object passed in.
        const urlSearchParamsClone = _.cloneDeep(urlSearchParams);
        // Merge in with a customizer to replace arrays instead of concat (default)
        const mergedSearchParams = _.mergeWith(
          urlSearchParamsClone,
          value,
          function (a, b) {
            if (Array.isArray(a)) {
              return b;
            }
          },
        );
        const serializedOriginal = serializeSearchParams(urlSearchParams);
        const serializedUpdated = serializeSearchParams(mergedSearchParams);

        if (serializedOriginal !== serializedUpdated) {
          setUrlSearchParams(mergedSearchParams);
        }
      }
    },
    [urlSearchParams, setUrlSearchParams],
  );

  return [urlSearchParams, updateUrlSearchParams] as const;
};
```

The issue that I'm running into when trying to call updateUrlSerachParams is that router.replace can sometimes run more than once taking in a previous version of search params and replacing it with the already updated version.

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to relate to how `router.replace` is called within an effect that triggers every time `urlSearchParams` changes. Due to the asynchronous nature of React's state updates and Next.js's router operations, `router.replace` may use stale state or query values.

Also If `router.replace` is called too frequently, it might lead to race conditions where the URL is updated with stale data. Debouncing these calls ensures that `router.replace` is only called after a certain period of inactivity, thus avoiding rapid, successive updates.

I have updated your code.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import _ from 'lodash';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'; // Make sure to import debounce

export const useUrlSearchParams = (defaults) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { query } = router;

  const [urlSearchParams, setUrlSearchParams] = useState(null);
  const pendingSearchParamsRef = useRef(null);

  // Debounce router.replace to avoid rapid updates
  const debouncedReplace = useCallback(
    debounce((nextQuery) => {
      router.replace({ query: nextQuery }, undefined, { scroll: false });
    }, 300), // Adjust debounce time as needed
    [],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      const { search } = query;
      const decodedSearchParams = search ? deserializeSearchParams(search) : defaults;
      setUrlSearchParams(decodedSearchParams);
      pendingSearchParamsRef.current = decodedSearchParams; // Set the initial ref state
    }
  }, [router.isReady, query, defaults]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (urlSearchParams !== null && !_.isEqual(urlSearchParams, pendingSearchParamsRef.current)) {
      const serializedSearchParams = serializeSearchParams(urlSearchParams);
      if (query['search'] !== serializedSearchParams) {
        pendingSearchParamsRef.current = urlSearchParams;
        debouncedReplace({ ...query, search: serializedSearchParams });
      }
    }
  }, [urlSearchParams, query, router, debouncedReplace]);

  const updateUrlSearchParams = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      if (urlSearchParams) {
        const urlSearchParamsClone = _.cloneDeep(urlSearchParams);
        const mergedSearchParams = _.mergeWith(
          urlSearchParamsClone,
          value,
          (a, b) => Array.isArray(a) ? b : undefined,
        );
        setUrlSearchParams(mergedSearchParams);
      }
    },
    [urlSearchParams],
  );

  return [urlSearchParams, updateUrlSearchParams];
};
```